# Problems: Setting up MSTest2012 on a jenkins server without installing VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, jenkins, mstest

I trying to setup `MSTest2012` on a jenkins server **without installing Visual Studio 2012** on it. I made it so far that I don't receive any "Assembly not found" error messages.

I was going to do some functional tests, so I copied a `vs2012` project from my local machine to my jenkins server and tried something like that in cmd:

```
C:\VS2011Stub\Common7\IDE>MSTest.exe /testcontainer:D:\Users\Jenkins\Documents\V
isualStudio2012\Projects\HelloWorld\UnitTestProject4\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject4.
dll
```

> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 11.0.50727.1
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading D:\Users\Jenkins\Documents\VisualStudio2012\Projects\HelloWorld\UnitTest
>   Project4\bin\Debug\UnitTestProject4.dll...
>   D:\Users\Jenkins\Documents\VisualStudio2012\Projects\HelloWorld\UnitTestProject4
>   \bin\Debug\UnitTestProject4.dll
>   **Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.**

This error message (Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht -> in english: **Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation**.) is pretty... unhelpfully.

On my **local machine** the same cmd-code looks like that:

[image]

I dont know what to do... any suggestions, solutions??? Maybe someone have the same problem :/ Maybe mstest2012 still need other files to run correctly??

Im happy about every help!

**edit:**
I followed these [steps](http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/mstest-2010-on-the-build-server-without-vs2010-installed/) to build MSTest.exe (VS2012) as standalone program on my jenkins server

**edit2:
!!!Problem solved!!!**

A few Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.#.dll's  in GAC folders i copied didnt contain a version=11.0.0.0, so i openend C:\Windows\Assembly an took a look at the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.# and checked the aviable versions and added the missing latest 11.0.0.0 Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.#.dll files on my jenkins server and registered them via gacutil(ver 4.0.30319.17929).

MSTest works now as stand alone program without installing MS Visual Studio 2012.

**If anybody needs an instruction file just ask and i will upload it =)**

Comment: At the risk of being "that guy", I'm not sure I'd be offering to publish copyrighted materials like this.

Comment: yesh, youre right! i was thinking on an instructions file when i talked about setup files, so everybody can do it on its own. i wont publish the microsoft files/dlls, my bad ;)